# What happened to w3-sidenav? Is it possible to use w3-sidebar instead without the drawbacks?

Tags: w3.css

What happened to `w3-sidenav`? We now only seem to have `w3-sidebar` which is not as good as it always displays in large (laptop, desktop) machines.

Is it possible to use `w3-sidebar`, but avoid the always-on problem for large screens? I want it visible only when I say.

Answer (score 0):

The w3 tutorials suggest that you use a class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block" to build a  side nav. You have different option of always display etc:

**1) Always Display:** Add Style="width=25%", and then to the adjacent div, add style="margin-left:25%"

**2)Open over content:** 
a) add to sidebar `style="display:none" id="mySideBar" <button onClick="we-close" class="w3-bar-iitem w3-large">Close &times; </button>`

b) Add to content (Adjacent Div): `<button class="w3-button w3-large" onClick="W3-open()">&#9776; </button>`

c) Add script

```
function w3-open(){ 
      document.getElementById("mySideBar").style.display="block";
   }
   function w3-close(){
      document.getElementById("mySideBar").style.display="none";
   }
```

Another option with this is to open the sidebar over the whole page, in which case you will use the same code as option 2 above, just add to the JS w3-open() function: `document.getElementById("mySideBar").style.width="100%";`

**3) Collapsible & Responsive: (I think this is the one you will probably prefer):** 
a) Define sidebar div with

```
class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card w3-animate-left" style="width: 200px" id="mySideBar">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large we-hide-large" onClick="w3-close()">close &times; </button>
```

b) Define the main wrapper div with

```
    <div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:200px"> 
       <div class="w3-blue"> 
         <button class="w3-button …." onClick="w3-open()"> &#9776; </button> 
       </div> 
   </div>
```

c) insert the javascript as per the above option 2, both w3-open() & w3-close()

***Do not quote my code above, I just typed it freehand, so its probably riddled with errors.***

[Here is the w3school script for option 3](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidebar_hide&stacked=h)

[You can read more about sidebars here.](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp)